# get url parameters and redirect printing a message

Tags: php

I have an index.php page and I'm using a switch statement to include scripts based on the uri (php request uri) and get the url parameters to do something (activate an account or change a password), then the method returns a message that is printed in the main html page.

The problem is the input url with the get parameters (from the url bar) are still present once the script is executed. And it will be executed again when the user press the login button.

I need to clear (or more exactly redirect, like header) the url from the bar and print the message returned from the method.

If I use header, the $msg will be lost and no message will be printed. If I use another get is the same story again.

```
// array whitelisting the permitted urls
// just 4: login, send_mail, recover_pwd and register (each pointing to his php file)
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
// some more security checks

if ($url != '/send_mail' && $url != '/recover_pwd' && $url != '/register' && $url != '/activateAccount')
    $url = '/login'; // this must be always the default page if none of the above are requested.

switch ($url) {
    case '/recover_pwd': // here users request a password change
        if (isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['email'])) {
            include('pages/rp_get.php'); // this is the get script(not included insde the array/html):
            //validates the code, changes the password and sends a mail with the new one then we have to redirect the user to the login page and print the message
            header('Location: /');  // this will clear the address bar and the $msg var
            }
        }
        break;
    case '/activateAccount': // this is just the script that validates the code and activates the account
        include('pages/activate_acc.php'); // (not included insde the array/html) then we have to redirect the user to the login page and print the message
        header('Location: /');
        }
        break;
    case '/login': // this is the login page
        include('pages/header_pages/login_post.php'); // the login post script must be before any DOM output so it can perfom a redirection using header()
        break;
    default: // i'm not sure if there should be a default case...
        $url = $url;
        break;
}

// include the main html
include('themes/aet/main.php');
```

And this is the main.php:

```
// HTML BASIC STRUCTURE
// BODY -> Header
// MAIN tags
<?php
$include = '/404';

if (array_key_exists($url, $includes)) {
    $include = $url; // this includes the pages from the array
}

include($includes[$include]);
?>

// here I print the msg (@ is just a temp hack)
if(@$msg != NULL) {
// check what type of message is and print it
}
```

I need to find a way to do this as clean as optimized. I would not want a heavy index page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: read it twice- confused as to what you want

Comment: Sorry, once the script is executed I need to redirect to the default page printing the returned message.

Comment: either put a variable in a session or add it to the url when you use LOCATION then you check that to decide what to display on main.php

Comment: I second the suggestion to use a session variable instead of url parameter.

Comment: Yeah of course, a session variable will do the job. I'm going to try that.

Comment: just make sure to remove it from the session after its been used or any one returning may get the wrong message

Comment: Ok, everything's working, thanks!